# Why can't I do proper iteration over two-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Here's my code. I wanna pull up even elements. But all I can pull up is `4 4 4 4 4`.

```js
function f6() {
    let out = '';
    let a6 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [21, 34], [44, 56]];
    for (let i = 0; i < a6.length; i++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < a6[i].length; i++) {
            if (a6[i][i] % 2 == 0) {
                out += a6[i][i] + ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(out);
}

document.querySelector('button').onclick = f6;
```

```html
<button>Push!</button>
```

Why?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `i` for two different purposes? A variable cannot be two different things at once.

Comment: `a6[i][i]`.  You can see why this does not do what you want, right?  This is a facepalm, not a misunderstanding, right?  I mean, I can see how you did it.  especially since you wrote `i < a6[i].length`.  You just wandered away from sense at that point.  Maybe you should have written let `row = a6[i]` before your loop and then wrote `for (let i = 0; i < row.length; i++)` and refer to `row[i]`.  But really...c'mon.  You just needed someone to point out the facepalm, right?  There's no question that needs to be answered here.  I'm voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've used the same variable name, `i`, twice. Declaring `let i` inside your inner loop prevents you from accessing the `let i` from your outer loop. If you use a different variable name for iterating through each loop, e.g. `j`, then you should be fine.

If you only need to use the index for accessing values at that index, then you may instead want to try a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to avoid this problem altogether, e.g.:

```
const data = ... // 2D array

for (let row of data) {
    for (let cell of row) {
        // Use cell here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your placeholder variable `i` is getting Shadowed by the second iteration, therefore you may want to use another placeholder such as `j` to have the correct reference to the element.

```js
  function f6() {
    let out = '';
    let a6 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [21, 34], [44, 56]];
    for (let i = 0; i < a6.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < a6[j].length; j++) {
            if (a6[i][j] % 2 == 0) {
                out += a6[i][j] + ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(out);
}

document.querySelector('button').onclick = f6;
```

```html
<button>Push!</button>
```

Comment: _Shadowed_, not overwritten.

Comment: would you care to explain more? What's the difference?

Comment: When you do something like `let i = 0; { let i = 1; }`, nothing is overwritten. There are two variables `i`. The first one holds the value `0`, and its scope is everywhere. The second `i` holds `1`, whose scope is only inside the block. Referencing `i` evaluates to the variable of the closest scope. Since both variables have the same name, inside the block, `i` refers to the variable holding `1`. The close-scoped variable shadows the other. The variables don’t overwrite each other at all. Once execution leaves this block, the outer `i` is accessible again.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks for your insight